# Laravel query with relationship has many duplicated query

Tags: laravel, foreach, duplicates

**Table A**

- id
- fullname
- branch_code

**Table B**

- id
- branch_code
- branch_name

I want to show list Table A with their branch name

here is the relation in table A

```
public function Branch () {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Branch','branch_code','branch_code');   
    }
```

here is the controller

```
 $TableA= TableA::orderBy('created_at','ASC')->get();
```

here is my blade

```
@foreach($TableAas $data)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $i }}</td>
    <td>{{$data->fullname}}</td>
    <td>{{$data->Branch->branch_name}}</td>
</tr>
  @endforeach
```

actually it works. but when i debug, i saw many duplicate queries like this

```
select top 1 * from [users] where [users].[branch_code] = '1001'
```

select top 1 * from [users] where [users].[branch_code] = '1002'
39.46ms
view::index:267

is there any way to make the query more simple and fast?
thank u

Answer (score 2):

use with to load relation

```
 $TableA= TableA::with('Branch')->orderBy('created_at','ASC')->get();
```

check EagerLoading problem and N+1 problem

Comment: hi, thank u for ur comment. i already try with this, and it works. but how if i have 3 relationship like this $tableA->Branch->tableC. so tableC have relationship to table B. if using like that, it still show duplicate query for 3 relationship. i try add with('Branch','TableC') but error

Comment: Try this for nested relations
$TableA= TableA::with(['Branch','Branch.tableC'])->orderBy('created_at','ASC')->get();